# DynamoDB Pojo to attribute value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a POJO defined for a dynamodb Table like this:

```html
public class DynamoDBTablePojo {

    @NonNull
    private String requestId;

    @NonNull
    private String responseId;

    private String responseBlob;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "RequestId")
    public String getRequestId(){return this.requestId;};

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ResponseId")
    public String getResponseId(){return this.responseId;};

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ResponseBlob")
    public String getResponseBlob() {return responseBlob;}
}
```

I want to write a function in java which will take attribute name and DynamoDBTablePojo object and returns the value of that attribute. e.g.,

```html
String func(String attributeName, DynamoDBTablePojo dynamoDBTablePojoObj){
 // returns value associated with this attribute.
}
```